# Cannot refuse bluetooth permission request

Tags: android, bluetooth

Ok, so I'm working on an app that uses bluetooth.
Here is the code where I check if bluetooth is enabled:

```
public void checkBluetoothState() {
    //check if the Device supports bluetooth
    if(bluetoothAdapter == null) {
        textState.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.btNotSupported));
    } else {
        //check if bluetooth is enabled
        if(bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            if(bluetoothAdapter.isDiscovering()) {
                textState.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.btDiscovering));
            } else {
                textState.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.btEnabled));                    
                buttonScanDevices.setEnabled(true);
            }               
        } else {
            textState.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.btDisabled));
            Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivity(enableBtIntent);
        }
    }
}
```

This is called in the onResume() method.

But when I refuse to activate bluetooth, the dialog just pops up again and again until I grant access or close the app.

Why is that?

Comment: Which dialog exactly pops-up and what are the condition of its appearing? The function here just checks if the BT is supported, then if yes, if it's enabled etc. If the bluetooth isDiscovering, when calling this function, it will re-enable it on the last else clause each time. if bluetoothAdapter .isDiscovering() is true, then this will never get inside the `if(bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled())` I think.

Comment: When I start the app and bluetooth isn't enabled startActivity(enableBtIntent); opens a dialog where I can enable bluetooth

Comment: I'm soory, but what does it have to do with the function you provided? Can you give me the code where `startActivity(enableBtIntent);` is called, you might be looping there.

Comment: It's in the code in the last else clause.

Comment: Then I guess that you can provide me with the `startActivity(Intent);` by editing your main thread?

Comment: It is in the main thread. Doesn't it show?

Comment: I mean, what does this function do? Can you provide the code. It's looping there by my opinion.

Comment: Oh sorry, it's from the Activity class. See [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivity%28android.content.Intent%29)

Comment: Why don't you try this: Replace `BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE` with `bluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE` just to see if you're not enabling another instance of the BluetoothAdapter, but in your propper instane you didn't receive `RESULT_OK`.

Comment: Hey I think I found the loop: The problem was that I called `checkBluetoothState()` in the `onResume()` method. So when the request dialog closes, `onResume()` and thus `checkBluetoothState()` is  called again. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You're wellcome, not that I helped a lot :-) Try debugging it the next time :-)